# How to automatically update GUI whenever data source changes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, push

Here is something I need to accomplish:

WPF datagrid display/bind data from SQL through entity data model, it also could be done by observationcollection through view model. I can read/pull and save the data successfully, My question is if there is a way to update the GUI data when the data is changed from data source without application pulling the data - meaning some mechanism notify UI the changes in data source and update UI Accordingly.

Or something like RSS feed in WPF Application, whenever data change in database, database/service push the data to GUI application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF and Silverlight you are binding the UI elements to properties of an object, that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. That object is usually your View Model, that represents the Model data as its properties. Wherever the data in the model is changed, you need to get the View Model to notify the UI to re-query the data to refresh the UI.

With that said - no, there is no way to bind directly to a database. You should bind to your data layer, which, in turn, should be polling the DB for changes.

Comment: Thank you for response, Is there other ways to implement such push/notify mechanism? Like stock price under finance.yahoo.com, the price changes without refreshing the webpage, any suguestions?

Comment: You are mixing two different things. In WPF the UI refresh is done either manually from code, or be changing the View Model. On the web sites like finance.yahoo.com, there most likely is a binding with AJAX. Whenever the data changes, a java script is executed, that updates the HTML. Data binding is merely an illusion in this case. It is data bound, but not database bound.